# Integral yielding part of a harmonic series

Tags: calculus

Why is this true?
$$\int_0^\infty x \frac{M}{c} e^{(\frac{-x}{c})} (1-e^{\frac{-x}{c}})^{M-1} \,dx = c \sum_{k=1}^M \frac{1}{k}.$$

I already tried substituting $u = \frac{-x}{c}$. Thus, $du = \frac{-dx}{c}$ and $-c(du) = dx$. Then, the integral becomes (after cancellation) $\int_0^\infty c u M e^u (1-e^u)^{M-1}\,du$.

I looked at integral-table.com, and this wasn't there, and I tried wolfram integrator and it told me this was a "hypergeometric integral".

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you substitute $t=1-e^{-x/c}$ your integral becomes
$I_M=-c\int_0^1\log(1-t)Mt^{M-1}dt=-c\int_0^1\log(1-t)(t^M)'dt$. Hence $I_M-I_{M-1}=-c\int_0^1\log(1-t)(t^{M-1}(t-1))'dt=c\int_0^1 t^{M-1} dt$ (by per partes) $=c/M$. So you only need to compute $I_1$, which is $c$.

(there should be a nicer solution)

Comment: That *was* pretty nice, I think. :)

Comment: Hi user8268, I read your explanation and I think I understand. This is my interpretation:
The original integral was to solve $I_M$. We have found the quantity $I_M - I_{M-1}$. We also know the quantities $I_{M-1}-I_{M-2}$, and so on, all the way down to infinity. By using telescoping sum, if we add all the increments, we get $I_M$. The sum stops partway at $I_0 = 0$. That is, all the increments "above" $I_0$, we need for the sum, but all the increments "below" $I_0$, they all sum up to zero. (Won't there be a term $I_{-\infty}$, though?)

Comment: $I_M = (I_M - I_{M-1}) + (I_{M-1} + I_{M-2}) + \cdots + I_{-\infty} = $.
$=(I_M - I_{M-1}) + (I_{M-1} + I_{M-2}) + \cdots + (I_1 - I_0) + (I_0 - I_{-1}) + (I_{-1} - I_{-2}) + \cdots + I_{-\infty}$. 
But $I_0 = 0$ and $I_{-1} = (I_{-1} - I_{-2}) + (I_{-2} - I_{-3}) + (I_{-3} - I_{-4}) + \cdots + I_{-\infty}$. So, $I_M = (I_M - I_{M-1}) + (I_{M-1} + I_{M-2}) + \cdots + (I_1 - 0)$.

Comment: @jrand: right: $I_M=(I_M-I_{M-1})+(I_{M-1}-I_{M-2})+\dots+(I_1-I_0)+I_0$. And $I_0=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Careful, the substitution changes the limits of integration.  It needs to be the integral going over negative real numbers.

You could just expand $(1-e^u)^{M-1}$ in $$\int_0^{-\infty} c u M e^u (1-e^u)^{M-1}\,du$$ to get

$$cM \int_0^{-\infty} u \sum_{n=0}^{M-1} \binom{M-1}{n} (-1)^n e^{(n+1)u}du.$$  Rearrange the integral and sum to find

$$cM \sum_{n=0}^{M-1} \binom{M-1}{n} (-1)^n  \int_0^{-\infty}  u e^{(n+1)u}du.$$  The anti-derivative of $xe^{rx}$ is $\frac{x}{r}e^{rx}-\frac{1}{r^2}e^{rx}$.

Can you solve it from here?

Comment: Hm. After calculating the integral, and doing substituting the factorials in, I get this:
$c \sum_{n=0}^{M-1} \frac{M!}{n!(M-1-n!)} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^2}$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_M$ are independent exponential random variables with mean $c$, so that their pdf and cdf are given by $f(x)=c^{-1}e^{-x/c}$ and $F(x)=1-e^{-x/c}$, $x \geq 0$, respectively. Let $Y_M=\max \{X_1,\ldots,X_M\}$. Then, $Y_M$ has cdf $F_M (x) = F(x)^M$ and hence pdf $f_M (x) = M F(x)^{M-1} f(x)$. Thus, the expectation of $Y_M$ is given by
$$
{\rm E}[Y_M ] = \int_0^\infty  {xMF(x)^{M - 1} f(x)dx}  = \int_0^\infty  {x\frac{M}{c}e^{ - x/c} (1 - e^{ - x/c} )^{M-1}dx}. 
$$
So you want to know why
$$
{\rm E}[Y_M] = c\sum\limits_{k = 1}^M {\frac{1}{k}}.
$$
Now, $Y_M$ is equal in distribution to $E_1 + \cdots + E_M$ where the $E_k$ are independent exponentials and $E_k$ has mean $c/k$; for this fact, see James Martin's answer to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52493/expected-second-moment-for-random-points-on-a-circle) (where $c=1$). The result is thus established.

EDIT: As an additional reference, see Example 4.22 on p. 157 in the book [Probability, stochastic processes, and queueing theory](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=9wtqv2VF7LMC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22maximum%20of%20n%20independent%20exponential%22&source=bl&ots=wD0W0rZJgI&sig=CeK1ppPwBf8bO2DMTQCwgU9VpZY&hl=iw#v=onepage&q=%22maximum%20of%20n%20independent%20exponential%22&f=false) by Randolph Nelson.

EDIT: It is interesting to note that
$$
\int_0^\infty  {x\frac{M}{c}e^{ - x/c} (1 - e^{ - x/c} )^{M - 1} dx}  = c\int_0^1 { - \log (1 - x^{1/M} )dx} .
$$
This follows by using a change of variable $x \mapsto x/c$ and then $x \mapsto (1-e^{-x})^M$.
So, this gives the following integral representation for the $M$-th harmonic number $H_M := \sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^M {\frac{1}{k}}$:
$$
H_M = \int_0^1 { - \log (1 - x^{1/M} )dx}. 
$$
Finally, it is both interesting and useful to note note
$$
H_M  = \int_0^1 {\frac{{1 - x^M }}{{1 - x}}dx}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^M {( - 1)^{k - 1} \frac{1}{k}{M \choose k}}, 
$$
see [Harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).
With the above notation, the right-hand side corresponds to
$$
{\rm E}[Y_M] = \int_0^\infty  {{\rm P}(Y_M  > x)dx}  = \int_0^\infty  {[1 - F_M (x)]dx} .
$$